# Why Eloquent Select as id returns zero "0"

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

A Laravel 5.8 Eloquent Query to a model with a select `field` as `id` returns 0 for that field

Consider this eloquent query `$users = User::select("SELECT email AS id", "name")->where('email', 'LIKE', '%gmail.com')->get();`
`$user->id;` is "0" !!

Why? and what's the correct way to do such a query so that `$user->id` is the user's email for this case?

Comment: Since `id` is an integer column, Laravel casts the value to an integer.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir so how can i prevent the casting to an integer?

Comment: You can put `$public incrementing = false;` in your `User` model, but you shouldn't. This breaks `User::create($data)->id`. I strongly recommend that you don't use this kind of query. If you want to return a JSON response, take a look at [API resources](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-resources). Why do you want to "rename" the `email` column?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use `select` twice?

You can do this instead:

```
$users = User::select(['email AS id', 'name'])->where('email', 'LIKE', '%gmail.com')->get();
```

That will return a collection so iterating over it you can access the user id, which will return the email.

Comment: I did tested on my project and it works as expected. I don't know if you tried or you just play smart.

Comment: @AllanDereal editing your code does not makes you smarter, we can see the edited timestamp below the question, and if you cannot see, I use `array` within the `select` in order to select the columns, and my code returns a collection with the id containing the email as you expect.

Comment: Your solution works. I realised that the error was in my query. thanx

Comment: The error was in your query that's why you asked the question I guess. :) You can accept the answer then.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to find a single row or just a user so you have to use `->first()` instead `->get()`

```
$user = User::select("SELECT email AS id, name")->where('email', 'LIKE', '%gmail.com')->first();
```

Finally: `$user->id`

Comment: I don't think you understand my question!